# Magento2.3: How to create separate Myaccount dashboard?

Tags: magento2.3, registration, myaccount

We have a B2B registration with the options dealer, corporate and employee on our website. Customer can register any one of the option by filling the corresponding form.

Now what I wanted to implement is when a customer completed his/her registration, I want to show separate My Account dashboard with necessary links. How can I do that?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to hide some tabs which is coming in left sidebar for some customer groups and display new tabs for some customers. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I want to redirect to the corresponding My Account dashboard when the customer complete registration

Comment: Okay for tabs you can add conditions, and for dashboard page you can create different phtml template files and you can put conditions based on group and display accordingly.

Comment: What you want to change in dashboard? Can you please attach screenshots in question? So I can update you.

Comment: You can update scrrenshot like.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kGUhk5i9XIyvKDmODiWmhwFgolxGZ-pl/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, I have added a screenshot with what I have to display in separate my account dashboard. Please help.

Comment: Here please confirm, You have same layout for all customers in order page, Account Info page and Address page.

Comment: You just want to hide some tabs for some customer groups. Am I right here ?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100146/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-siva).

Comment: It's simple. You just need to add condition for all sidebar links.

Comment: Where I have to add condition to the sidebar links?

Comment: Okay I'll update that with my answer after some time. I'll add with description. So you'll get idea, How you can manage that all thing.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm waiting for your answer

Comment: This solution works for you ?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293461/how-to-show-my-account-link-in-frontend-after-succesfully-logged-in/293462?noredirect=1#comment421825_293462

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, I'm working on that. Update you shortly

Comment: I've updated my answer please review. @Siva

Comment: Did you tried this @Siva ?

Comment: Currently, I'm implementing my design and am getting an error, please see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293570/magento2-3-cannot-open-links-in-myaccount-dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I'll explain you this with one example.

We will need to display **My Wishlist** link only for `B2C Customer` and `B2C Employee` customer groups and not in `B2B Dealer` and `B2B Corporate`.

- All Sidebar links, we can find here in `customer_account.xml` in different modules under `customer_account_navigation` container.

Like if you want to find **My Wishlist** link then you check this file..

> vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

**My Account** link located here in this file..

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

**My Orders** link located here in this file..

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

- So I think now you get idea how sidebar links are working. And you need to add any new links there then you can add that there.

So we will create this file here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/customer_account.xml

Here we need to change `Class name` for wishlist link and we will add new Class name there. So we can not change class name with `referenceBlock` so we will override class with `block` itself. So just copy entire block from there and add that in custom theme's `customer_account.xml` file and update your class name.

Content for above file is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Account\WishlistLink" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active" name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wish List</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

- Here I've changed Block's class name from `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface` to `Vendor\Module\Block\Account\WishlistLink`.

So now we need to create one Block file in our custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Account/WishlistLink.php

Content for this file is ..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Account;

class WishlistLink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    protected $customerGroup;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup,
        array $data = []
     ) {
         $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
         $this->customerGroup = $customerGroup;
         parent::__construct($context, $defaultPath, $data);
     }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
        $customerGroups = $this->customerGroup->toOptionArray();

        foreach ($customerGroups as $customerGroup) {
            if($customerGroup['value'] == $customerGroupId){
                $currentCustomerGroup = $customerGroup['label'];
            }
        }

        if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            if(in_array($currentCustomerGroup, array("B2C Customer", "B2C Employee"))) {
                return parent::_toHtml();
            } else {
                return; 
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

- Here in this file I've added **Customer Group's** Condition. So now if any customer has `B2C Customer` and `B2C Employee` Group that customer only can see "My Wishlist" link in account dashboard page.

You can do same thing for different links same as above. You can create different Block files and you can override multiple block's class name in xml file.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks. It's very descriptive. Hopefully I will get the output. Update you once done

Comment: Okay no problem @Siva

Comment: What I have to put in value at if($customerGroup['value'] == $customerGroupId){
                $currentCustomerGroup = $customerGroup['label'];
            }

Comment: In that for each loop you do not need to change anything there.

Comment: You just need to change B2C B2B etc means you customer groups in if condition

Comment: Okay, Thanks! working on this and let you know the status. You're so helpful. Thank you so much again

Comment: I just tried for the customer group "General" with your code but it showing all the links. Please guide me

Comment: Can you please confirm you've created files properly?

Comment: Yes. I have created the block file, layout as you said

Comment: Okay I'll send you a link within few mins. You can download that module and you can check.

Comment: Sure..  I'm using Enterprise Edition. Does the module works on EE?

Comment: Yes, I've created that module and that will work for both Enterprise and Community. Please check this (https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-magento2-hide-account-sidebar-tabs)

Comment: Okay. I will check. Thanks

Comment: Approve my answer and give me an upvote if above solution is helpful to you. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Sure. I will do that.. since I'm in holidays i didn't check that yet. Once I checked the solution, will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Did you checked this ? If this will helpful to you then let me know.

Comment: I have installed the module and didn't change anything. Now after installing the module, the menu "Mywishlist" is not displaying. Can you please guide me on that?

Comment: @Siva, Please comment this code and clear cache and then check.

if(in_array($currentCustomerGroup, array("B2C Customer", "B2C Employee"))) {
                return parent::_toHtml();
            } else {
                return; 
            }

Comment: Now, I have the code as this: if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            //if(in_array($currentCustomerGroup, array("B2C Customer", "B2C Employee"))) {
            if(in_array($currentCustomerGroup, array("B2C Customer"))) { // I've added 'B2C Customer' here in Condition so 'My Wishlist link only visible for B2C Customer customer group's customers only.
                return parent::_toHtml();
            } else {
                return; 
            }
        }

Comment: Could you please let me know whatelse I have to comment?

Comment: @Siva please add this line **return parent::_toHtml();** in your **_toHtml()** function's first line. So you will get idea.

Comment: What I did in my answer's code. If customer's group is **"B2C Customer", "B2C Employee"** then they can see "Wishlist" link, not any other groups of customer can see "Wishlist" link. Hope you will not understand this.

Comment: I understood your answer and what you're trying to say is. Now I have put only "B2C Customer" so as per understanding only the "wishlist" link should be displayed and not other links. Am I right? But what I'm getting is "wishlist" link is hidden and all other links are displaying.

Comment: Little misunderstanding here, If you will add condition for wishlist link for "B2C Customer" group only then only "B2C" Customers can able to see that link not any other group of customer can see that link, this code will not effect all other links.

Comment: I'm having little bit confusion. That is how can I confirm that whether My Account Dashboard belongs to B2C, B2B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100666/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-siva).

Comment: @Siva click here and find my answer there **Let us continue this discussion in chat.**

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options for this approach.

1. You can **override my Account Page** and Customize.

   **or**
2. You can add new page and **set default open to that corresponding page**.

   **or**
3. You can also create one module for setting up **menus visibilty option according to your user group**.

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thanks. Since there are multiple approaches, I would like to know which one is good?

Comment: I think last one approach is good, set menus visibility according to user and also set default page for all of them(according to level).

Comment: I think add new pages and set default open is easy approach. Please guide

Comment: Yes, you can go with second approach as well, this is very easy and time consuming approach.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more if I go with option 3?

Comment: You have to set multiple conditions on visibility to user like, if(admin){show my account menu}else if(user){show my summary menu}.