# Magento2.3: Cannot open links in Myaccount dashboard

Tags: magento2.3, phtml, design, myaccount

I'm implementing my own design to My Account dashboard. Unfortunately, I'm not able to open the Address Book and Address Information. When am clicking those links, I'm getting the below attached error.

[image]

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name $block */

/*
<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')
   ->setObject($block->getAddress())
   ->toHtml() ?>

For checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml:

<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')
   ->setObject($block->getAddress())
   ->setFieldIdFormat('shipping:%s')
   ->setFieldNameFormat('shipping[%s]')
   ->toHtml() ?>
*/

$prefix = $block->showPrefix();
$middle = $block->showMiddlename();
$suffix = $block->showSuffix();
?>
<?php if (($prefix || $middle || $suffix) && !$block->getNoWrap()): ?>
<div class="field required fullname <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getContainerClassName()) ?>">
    <label for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <fieldset class="fieldset fieldset-fullname">
        <div class="fields">
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($prefix): ?>
        <div class="field field-name-prefix<?php if ($block->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' required' ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php if ($block->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('prefix')) ?>"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>"
                           class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"
                            name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('prefix')) ?>"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>"
                            class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?> >
                        <?php foreach ($block->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option) ?>"<?php if ($block->getObject()->getPrefix() == $_option): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_option)) ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="address-row-wrap">
        <div class="col-6">
        <div class="field field-name-firstname single-row required">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('firstname')) ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?>"
                       class="input-text my-account-input <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php if ($middle): ?>
        <?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $block->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
        <div class="field field-name-middlename<?= $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' required' : '' ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('middlename')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('middlename')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('middlename')) ?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('middlename')) ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('middlename')) ?>"
                       class="input-text my-account-input <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename')) ?>" <?= $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' data-validate="{required:true}"' : '' ?>>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="field field-name-lastname single-row required">
              <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('lastname')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?></span></label>
              <div class="control">
                  <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('lastname')) ?>"
                         name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('lastname')) ?>"
                         value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>"
                         title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?>"
                         class="input-text my-account-input <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php if ($suffix): ?>
        <div class="field field-name-suffix<?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' required' ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php if ($block->getSuffixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('suffix')) ?>"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getSuffix()) ?>"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?>"
                           class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"
                            name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('suffix')) ?>"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?>"
                            class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($block->getSuffixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option) ?>"<?php if ($block->getObject()->getSuffix() == $_option): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_option)) ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (($prefix || $middle || $suffix) && !$block->getNoWrap()): ?>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please update some more infor here ?

Comment: I have directly added my custom classes into the core files but am not sure where am I wrong.

Comment: In which file you've added classes ?

Comment: Is that XML file?

Comment: No, its phtml file

Comment: Can you please send me that file's path and what changes you've made there please ?

Comment: It saying that the error is on /var/www/html/newmagento/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml

Comment: Okay then can you please backup that file and revert your changes with default Magento file once and check ?

Comment: The problem is I didn't take backup. I have included the code at question. How can i resolve this issue? Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `.phtml` file with this content..

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name $block */

/*
<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')
   ->setObject($block->getAddress())
   ->toHtml() ?>

For checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml:

<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')
   ->setObject($block->getAddress())
   ->setFieldIdFormat('shipping:%s')
   ->setFieldNameFormat('shipping[%s]')
   ->toHtml() ?>
*/

$prefix = $block->showPrefix();
$middle = $block->showMiddlename();
$suffix = $block->showSuffix();
?>
<?php if (($prefix || $middle || $suffix) && !$block->getNoWrap()): ?>
<div class="field required fullname <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getContainerClassName()) ?>">
    <label for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <fieldset class="fieldset fieldset-fullname">
        <div class="fields">
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($prefix): ?>
        <div class="field field-name-prefix<?php if ($block->isPrefixRequired()): echo ' required'; endif; ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php if ($block->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('prefix')) ?>"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>"
                           class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix')) ?>" <?php if($block->isPrefixRequired()): echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"'; endif; ?>>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"
                            name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('prefix')) ?>"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>"
                            class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isPrefixRequired()): echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"'; endif; ?> >
                        <?php foreach ($block->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option) ?>"<?php if ($block->getObject()->getPrefix() == $_option): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_option)) ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="address-row-wrap">
        <div class="col-6">
        <div class="field field-name-firstname single-row required">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('firstname')) ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?>"
                       class="input-text my-account-input <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') == 'required-entry'): echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"'; endif; ?>>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php if ($middle): ?>
        <?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $block->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
        <div class="field field-name-middlename<?= $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' required' : '' ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('middlename')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('middlename')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('middlename')) ?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('middlename')) ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('middlename')) ?>"
                       class="input-text my-account-input <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename')) ?>" <?= $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' data-validate="{required:true}"' : '' ?>>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="field field-name-lastname single-row required">
              <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('lastname')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?></span></label>
              <div class="control">
                  <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('lastname')) ?>"
                         name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('lastname')) ?>"
                         value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>"
                         title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?>"
                         class="input-text my-account-input <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') == 'required-entry'): echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"'; endif; ?>>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php if ($suffix): ?>
        <div class="field field-name-suffix<?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()): echo ' required'; endif; ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php if ($block->getSuffixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('suffix')) ?>"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getSuffix()) ?>"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?>"
                           class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"
                            name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('suffix')) ?>"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?>"
                            class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()): echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"'; endif; ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($block->getSuffixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option) ?>"<?php if ($block->getObject()->getSuffix() == $_option): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_option)) ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (($prefix || $middle || $suffix) && !$block->getNoWrap()): ?>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In your **if** conditions **endif** missing everywhere.

You can use if condition like this if you want to add class in html

```
<div class="test <?php if($somecondition): echo 'required'; endif; ?>">Test</div>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but its not working. Is it possible to remove and regenerate all the folder in vendor directory because i'm not sure where I have updated.

Comment: What error now you're getting there ? Can you please let me know ?

Comment: Seen that I have closed the div after endif that's caused the issue.